# Pass a command string with space to docker-compose exec

Tags: bash, docker-compose, barman

Real life scenario: In my automation script, there is a cli to run `barman recover` on a barman container. However it's possible to pass the `"ssh xxx"` as a whole string arg to the `--remote-ssh-command`, and barman reports "barman: error: unrecognized arguments: postgres@IP -p 60022"

```sh
docker-compose exec -T barman barman recover SRV1 last /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/recovered.streaming  --remote-ssh-command "ssh postgres@IP -p 60022"

# I tried with bach -c trick, still no luck.
docker-compose exec -T barman bash -c "barman recover SRV1 last /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/recovered.streaming  --remote-ssh-command 'ssh postgres@IP -p 60022'"
```

To simplify, imagine a minimal reproducing case:

```sh
docker-compose exec -T barman bash -c "echo hello"
# (It echos nothing. But I want it to behave like the following.)

docker-compose exec -T barman echo hello
# hello
```

The question is, how to pass a quoted string arg through `docker-compose exec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution: use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`.

```sh
docker compose exec -T barman bash -c "echo hello"
# hello

docker-compose exec -T barman echo hello
# hello
```

I believe the Python version (docker-compose) doesn't process the arguments with space well. Fortunately the Go version (docker compose) doesn't have such a problem.

I tried @Fravadona 's answer, but unluckily in Alpine Linux the `printf` does not have `%q`.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like you need to escape the remote command twice (the first escaping is done with the double-quotes):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose exec -T barman \
    barman recover \
    SRV1 last /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/recovered.streaming \
    --remote-ssh-command "$(printf %q "ssh postgres@IP -p 60022")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It may work on BASH, but sadly I am using Alpine Linux as the Docker Base Image, so %q is not supported.